# Differential Equation Mixture Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

A large tank starts with $900L$ of water. At time $t = 0$, a solution with a concentration of $1g/L$ is pumped in at a rate of $10L/min$. The solution is then pumped out at $8L/min$. Let x(t) denote the amount of solution in the tank at time $t$. How do I set up an equation for an initial value problem? The general formula is $\frac{dy}{dx}=$rate in - rate out. So that's $\frac{dy}{dx}=(1g/L)(10L/min)-($concentration in tank$)(8L/min)$. My goal is to get the equation an equation in the form $x(t)=...$, how do I do that?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $10$ - $\frac{8}{900}$$y$ is the differential equation. You can solve it by using seperation of variables.

Comment: @BrendanSullivan sorry, but it would but much appreciated if you can show me how you arrived at this equation, specifically $\frac{8}{900}y$. I know that the initial value is 900L and that it is pumped out at 8L/min. However, I'm not sure if they can be multiplied together like this. I will solve it myself afterwards

Comment: The rate out part of the differential equation $\frac{8}{900}$$y$ comes from the same way you find the rate in. You multiply the concentration of salt by the rate at which the water is leaving the tank. The concentration of salt in tank can be written as $\frac{grams of salt in tank}{volume of tank}$. So the concentration becomes $\frac{y}{900}$. The reason why you multiply by $y$ is because $y$ denotes the amount in the tank at any time. Then you multiply by the rate that the water is leaving the tank, which is $8\frac{L}{min}$. That is how I got $\frac{8}{900}$$y$.